# Set the parametric equation of an arc with two points

Tags: parametric, vector-fields, parametrization

Like the title says, I am looking for a method to find the parametric equation expressed in the form  $\vec{r}=...\vec{i}+...\vec{j}$ of the arc that connects the points (2,0) and (1,2). I am asking for this, because it is the step that is stopping me to compute the value of a vector field.

Thank you.

Comment: An arc, the arc, any arc, what arc? One parametrization of the line segment is $(2+ -1\cdot t,0+2t)$, where $0\le t\le1$. (The value of $t$ represents the fraction of the way you are from the first point to the second point.)

Comment: Sorry, I was talking about an arc of a circle, I thought that an arc was an arc. Can you explain a little bit more what do you mean by "represents the fraction of the way you are from the first point to the second point".

Comment: As others have pointed out, there are many circles through the given points. Parametric equations for a circle, given the center and radius, are easy enough to find or figure out, so perhaps pick a center (anywhere on the perpendicular bisector of your points), calculate the radius, and go from there.

Comment: Ok, probably easier to work in polar coordinates with the radius and angle as the borders of integration. I will try, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several commenters have noted that the arc you want to define is not unique; there are an infinity of such arcs. More precisely, there is a natural parametrization of such arcs by a single variable and a choice of orientation, which I describe below.

When you draw the situation on paper, you will see that the center of the circle must exist on the line which is the perpendicular bisector of the line segment between the two points. We can prove this: if the two given points are $A$ and $B$, their midpoint is $C$, and $O$ is the center of such a circle, then:

- $OA$ and $OB$ must have the same length
- $\Delta OAB$ is isosceles
- $\Delta OCA\cong \Delta OCB$ by side-angle-side [this one you probably have to draw to see]
- $\angle OCA \cong \angle OCB$
- Since $A,B,C$ are colinear, the measures of those angles must sum to $180^\circ$.
- Since they are equal, $m\angle OCB = \left(\frac{180}2\right)^\circ$
- Thus, $O$ lies on the line perpendicular to $CB$ and passing through $C$, as desired.

Now we can find an explicit representation of this line; I will use vector notation. The line between $A=(a_0,b_0)$ and $B=(a,b)$ is given by this one-variable ($t$) vector equation:
$$ \begin{bmatrix} x\\y \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} a-a_0\\b-b_0 \end{bmatrix} t + \begin{bmatrix} a_0\\b_0 \end{bmatrix}. $$

Since $C=(\frac{a+a_0}{2},\frac{b+b_0}{2})$, we have that the perpendicular line is given by
$$ \begin{bmatrix} x\\y \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} b_0-b\\a-a_0 \end{bmatrix} t + \begin{bmatrix} \frac12(a+a_0)\\\frac12(b+b_0) \end{bmatrix}. $$

So each value of $t$ gives us a possible center for our circle.

At this point, we recall that a circle is given by $(x-h)^2+(y-k)^2=r^2$, where the center $O=(h,k)$ and the radius ($OA$, or $OB$) has length $r$. For a particular choice of $t$:

\begin{align*}
h &=(b_0-b)t+(a+a_0)/2 &&= -\beta t + \alpha/2 \\
k &=(a-a_0)t+(b+b_0)/2 &&= \alpha t + \beta/2 \\
r^2 &= \displaystyle \bigg[ (b_0-b)^2t^2 + (a-a_0)^2t^2\bigg] + \bigg[ \frac{(a-a_0)^2}{4} + \frac{(b-b_0)^2}{4} \bigg] &&= \textstyle(\alpha^2+\beta^2)(t^2+\frac14)
\end{align*}

where $\alpha=a-a_0$ and $\beta=b-b_0$. The calculation of $r^2$ comes from using the Pythagorean theorem on the triangle $\Delta OCA$: the first square-bracket is the length of $OC$ and the second is the length of $CA$ (using the distance formula).

We now pull all the data together to get a circle: You have $(a_0,b_0)=(2,0)$ and $(a,b)=(1,2)$ which means $\alpha=-1$ and $\beta=2$; thus

$$\textstyle(x-2t-\frac12)^2 + (y+t+1)^2 = \frac54 + 5t^2.$$

Now for the usual circle trick: Let $\theta$ be defined such that
$$\cos\theta = \frac{x-2t-\frac12}{\sqrt{\frac54+5t^2}} \qquad\qquad\text{and}\qquad\qquad \sin\theta = \frac{y+t+1}{\sqrt{\frac54+5t^2}} ~.$$
This means that this circle has parametric form
$$ \begin{bmatrix} x\\y \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 2t+\frac12\\-t-1 \end{bmatrix} + \sqrt{\frac54+5t^2}\begin{bmatrix} \cos\theta\\\sin\theta \end{bmatrix}. $$

[Remeber: $\theta$ is the only parameter here; the $t$ is just showing up because the circle is not uniquely defined. For each available arc, $t$ is just a specific constant number.]

Therefore, the only remaining task is to determine which range of $\theta$ will create the arc with endpoints $A$ and $B$. This can be done in general though a case-by-case analysis of possible $t$-values, but it is very tedious. The reason that it is not so simple to do it directly is that plugging in $x=2$ to the $\cos\theta=\cdots$ equation does not uniquely define $\theta$, even on the interval $[0,2\pi)$; one must also know at least the sign of $\sin\theta$ when $y=0$, and hence there are two cases to consider. A similar analysis happens with the parameters for $B$ inserted, so that there are now four cases to consider.

Finally, you have some flexibility to choose the $\theta$ values you choose for the endpoints, and the choices you make at this step are not totally immaterial. Of course you have freedom to choose either one up to adding a multiple of $2\pi$: the point is that by choosing the same multiple or consecutive multiples, and depending on which of the four cases you are in, you will change whether you get a major or minor arc.

Answer (score 1):

Try $r(t)=(-t,2t)+(2,0)=(2-t,2t)=(2-t)\ \vec i+2t\ \vec j$ with $0\le t\le 1$.

Comment: Can you explain how did you set it? For the points (1,0) and (2,0) I would us e $\vec{r}=(-t,0) + (2,0)$ ? I don't understand why.

Comment: the segment of a line which pass through two points $p,q$ it s $r(t)=(p-q)t+q$, with $0\le t\le 1$. Note that $r(0)=q$ and $r(1)=p$.

Comment: Isn't it the equation of a line ? We have an arc of a circle, we can use this equation too?

Comment: it is  a line. For a circle it is needed other expression, let me think

Comment: Look, for a couple of point pass an infinity of circles, but if you specify three points then it's gonna be an unique circle that touch them.

Comment: With the three points, can I still use the equation r(t)=(p−q)t+q ?

Comment: Sure, you can trace a line between two, and another line between other two to form a pair of lines connecting the three points

Comment: And adding those two equations will give me the final equation of the arc of the circle or we are using them and separating the surface in new surfaces and try to evaluate the integrals of each sub-surfaces?

Comment: the two lines between three points only is a polygonal path. I don't know of what surface or what integral you are talking about . Why don't you add more info to your question above?

Comment: by the way http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16209/how-to-determine-the-center-and-radius-of-a-circle-given-some-points-in-3d#16210